# How to display Java Hashmap.keySet() in a bootstrap table, from a java rest service?

Tags: javascript, java, html, rest, bootstrap-table

i'm trying to display a hashmap keyset in a bootstrap table, but only the first character is showing.

This is my rest service function:

```
@GET
@Path("getquizes")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Collection<String> getQuizes() {
    System.out.println(activeQuizes.keySet());
    return activeQuizes.keySet();
}
```

It is working. This is what i am receive:

[Received Json object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Su53.png)

Here is my Html:

```
         <table data-toggle="table" id="tablequizes" class="display table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th datatype="String">Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

And my javascript:

```
function fetchQuizes() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'rest/Quiz/getquizes',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.info(data);
            $('#tablequizes').bootstrapTable('load', data);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.info(result.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

But the result is only showing the first character in the array:

[Bootstrap datatable with hashmap keyset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxyYh.png)

Comment: Where does `bootstrapTable` come from? Is that a library you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting wrong about what the `keySet()` is giving you:

```
Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map.
```

You are getting only the key and not the value of the map. For getting the value use `values()`

```
Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map

activeQuizes.values(); //Try with this.
```

Comment: I am using a quiz name as a key. And i want a list of all the quizes in my website. Thats why i am using the keyset, because i only whant a list of the quizes names, and not the whole quiz object. As the picture shows, i am receiving a list of the quiz names, but the problem is to display it in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your ajax output content tablequizes to an Array with some name id in it in your JS.

```
Eg: [ {"name": "Quiz1"}, {"name": "Quiz2"} ]
```

And modify the th tag

```
<th data-field="name">Name</th>
```

This should solve your problem.